# append a style to a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

Here's my problem. I'm writing an editor which has syntax highlight. Nothing fancy but it does the job. The problem is that I'm implementing error recognition and when I want to add the style to underline the line, I'm overriding the style I had before. Here's a screenshot:

[image: true]
I'm doing something like this to add the new style:

```
            if(e.getListaErrori().size()>0){
                jcb.addItem("ERRORS FOUND");
                for(org.univpm.grail.error.Error i:e.getListaErrori()){
                    jcb.addItem(i.getError());
                    Element child = root.getElement(i.getLine()-1);
                    styleRoot.setCharacterAttributes(child.getStartOffset(), i.getInstr().length()-1, ta.getStyle("ErrUnder"), true);
                }
                jcb.setVisible(true);
            }
```

If I use `setCharacterAttributes` with the last argument to `false` we have:

[image: false]
That is **almost** what I want. I would like to have the underline of a different color. I realized it's impossibile...but...do you think is there a way to do it?

Comment: You may have to just paint the line on the screen.

Comment: could you point me to some tutorial. What I'm finding is just the ovverride of the paintComponent method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I want to add the style to underline the line, I'm overriding the style I had before.

Maybe instead of playing with the styles, you can just "highlight" the text by using a highlighter. [Rectangle Painter](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/rectangle-painter/) shows how to create a custom rectangle highlight. You should be able to change the code easily to just use a line highlight.

Comment: that works. If anyone needs it, you have just to fill the rectangle with your background color first and then g.draw it.